# How to use ReactDOM.render to mutate a DOM Element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Calling `ReactDOM.render(<span>Hello</span>, container)` will call `container.appendChild` when it renders. Then I can get that DOM node with `container.childNodes[0]`.

However, I want to be able to use ReactDOM to directly manipulate a DOM node. For example, suppose I already have a span and I just want to manipulate that span using React.

```
const span = document.createElement('span') // suppose this is given in a function argument for some other frontend library
ReactDOM.render(<span style={{color: 'blue'}}>Hello</span>, span)
```

Is there a way to make it so this doesn't create a child span but instead mutates the given span directly?

Comment: No, there is not. The only way you can manipulate existing, server-side rendered, HTML is to server-side render the HTML with React too and _hydrate_ it client-side. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring + https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#hydrate

Comment: Hmm. That's what I'm reading as well... That's really unfortunate though. Seems like such a useful utility...